# $.click works but $.focus doesnt work on same element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an instance where I am generating accordion panels as a 'parent data-set'. When a panel is clicked, a table with rows is generated dynamically. When the rows of the table are finished rendering, I want to set focus on the first row.

What is interesting is that the first accordion panel will open and set focus properly on the dynamic table rows. No row beyond the first will work. The panels will expand, but focus will not be set.

Furthermore, if I change my focus event to a click event, everything works fine.

Relevant psuedocode code from inside the accordion panel that dynamically gets generated:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(objIndex, obj) in vm.objects">
    <a href="#" id="obj_row_{{objIndex}}">Focus on me!</a>
</tr>
```

js that runs after accordion panel has been expanded:

```
$timeout(function(){
    var elementId = '#obj_row_' + index;
    $(elementId).focus();
});
```

in this case, nothing happens. if i change the .focus function to a .click call, the element is clicked, no matter what accordion panel has been opened.

Any advice on this? Thank you

Comment: The key to your issue is "*dynamic table rows*". You need to look into [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and specifically check out the sections that look something like `$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {`

Comment: You can't focus an `a` that doesn't have a `href` attribute. Plus the only valid children of `tr` are `th` or `td`

Comment: @turnip i forgot to place the href in the psuedo code. updated my question. thank you

Comment: @monkeyzeus i will look into that. thank you